# How to add images that were searched to an array then present them one by one in a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, slideshow

I am looking to add images to an array  by appending the outputted images based on what was searched. Before I implemented the array code, all of the photos would appear on the page, 15 or so. I hope to add them to an array and them show one at a time by adding a side. That is what I am trying to accomplish now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="imageSearch.css">
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-inline"  id="myForm" action="" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="item" name="imageSearch" placeholder="Search for an Image">
    </div> <br> <br>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">    <input class="btn btn-default" id="clear" type="button" value="Clear"> <br>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        search();
        return false;
    });
    function search() {
      var images =  new Array();
        var apiKey = '';
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type:'GET',
                    url:"https://api.gettyimages.com/v3/search/images/creative?phrase=" + $('#item').val(),
                    beforeSend: function (request)
                    {
                        request.setRequestHeader("Api-Key", apiKey);
                    }})
                .done(function(data){
                    console.log("Success with data")
                    for(var i = 0;i<data.images.length;i++)
                    {


                        images[i].src = " <img src='" + data.images[i].display_sizes[0].uri + "'/>" ;
                        $("#output").append(images[i]);

                    }
                })
                function nextImage(output)
{
    var img = document.getElementById("output");

    for(var i = 0; i < images.length;i++)
    {
        if(images[i].src == img.src) // << check this
        {
            if(i === images.length){
                document.getElementById("output").src = images[0].src;
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById("output").src = images[i+1].src;
            break;
        }
    }
}

                .fail(function(data){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data,2))
                });
        return false;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#clear").click(function()
  {
      $("#output").empty();

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that your actual api key and are you sure you want to post it here?

Comment: What is or isn't working? Not clear what specific problem is. We have no idea what you had before